# ViewSonic XG2431 cannot change brightness (Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: gnome, graphics, 22.04, multiple-monitors, brightness

I recently purchased a ViewSonic XG2431 and while using it, I noticed I cannot change the brightness. I am running Ubuntu 22.04, so I did not install any drivers. The monitor was able to connect to my laptop instantly via HDMI, but when going into the OSD settings, the brightness settings is grayed out. Any fixes?

Also, I should note that I'm running the monitor in 'Standard' ViewMode on factory settings. The factory response time is set to 'Standard' too (the lowest it can go).

Finally, in writing this, I tried using ddccontrol. I can successfully find my monitor, but the software gives me a warning that 'there is no support for your monitor in the database,' and thus it uses a generic profile. In the ddccontrol GUI, I can set the brightness from 0 to 100, but at 0, the brightness on the OSD of the monitor reads 40%, and at 100 on ddccontrol the monitor reads 100%. I still consider this not successful, since at 40%, the monitor is still pretty bright.

Any help would be much appreciated!!

(FYI I also cross-posted this in r/monitors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out with the help of u/Specialist_Put_9497 on Reddit. Turns out that if the monitor's ECO Mode setting is on 'Energy Saving,' then brightness functionality is disabled. Turning onto any other setting besides 'Energy Saving' will let you control brightness.